# ReactiveUI WhenAnyValue

Tags: reactiveui

i have this code, but when i run, i throw an exception. I try to read document but i'm not Know, where am i Wrong?

```cs
public bool IsCanvasMouseOn
{
    get => this._isCanvasMouseOn;
    set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _isCanvasMouseOn, value);
}

public Visibility DynamicInputVisibility => this._dynamicInputVisibility.Value;

this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.IsCanvasMouseOn)
                .Select(visibility => visibility ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed)
                .StartWith(Visibility.Collapsed)
                .DistinctUntilChanged()
                .ToProperty(this, x=>DynamicInputVisibility,out _dynamicInputVisibility);
```

`System.ArgumentException: 'Property expression must be of the form 'x => x.SomeProperty''`

Comment: The exception is telling you to do x => x.DynamicInputVisibility instead of x => DynamicInputVisibility

Answer (score 4):

It's your last line

```cs
ToProperty(this, x=>DynamicInputVisibility,out _dynamicInputVisibility);
```

It should be

```cs
ToProperty(this, x=> x.DynamicInputVisibility,out _dynamicInputVisibility);
```